# Manipulations in a user control on a nested canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to capture manipulations on a canvas in a user control structured as follows:

```
<UserControl IsManipulationEnabled="true">    
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasContainer" Width="1500" Height="780">
        <ZoomableCanvas ManipulationStarting="ShareSwarmCanvas_OnManipulationStarting" ApplyTransform="false" x:Name="ShareSwarmCanvas" Width="1500" Height="780" MinWidth="1500" MinHeight="780" />
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

If I add a 'ManipulationStarting' event to the control and handled it, it captures fine and passes the UserControl as the sender. However I can't capture on the nested canvas even if I set 'IsManipulationEnabled=true' on it. I understand that the routed events bubble down until handled and I am handling it. It isn't a stacking issue?

Comment: Allied to the above, is there a way to trace where manipulations events are being handled?

Comment: I have not used Snoop in over a year, but last time I used it, it allowed you to trace an event route and show you which element in the route marked it as handled: http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Ameen, I'm on the Pixelsense SDK and Snoop doesn't seem to work. But I'll do some reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple in the end as always. Add a background property to the `UIElement`.